# Is every linear differential equation solvable using the standard method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asking this question because I was not able to find the solution to this linear differential equation.
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx} + 3xy = \sin(x) $$

Comment: What's the standard method?

Comment: @Gae.S. I assume they mean the integrating factor method

Comment: I’m fairly sure it is possible to use the integrating factor method here: you might get $ye^{3x}=\int\sin(x)e^{3x}\,dx$

Comment: @IdioticShrike  it's  $\mu(x)=e^{3x^2/2}$ then  it's hard to integrate the RHS.

Comment: @Aryadeva Ah of course. Does this now render the RHS integral unsolvable? $\int\sin(x)e^{\frac{3x^2}{2}}\,dx$?

Comment: I didn't try to solve it. It seems like it's hard at first sight. But it's obvious that $e^{3x} \sin x$ is easier to integrate @IdioticShrike This is maybe the reason OP couldnt integrate the DE.

Comment: Might be worth to share your efforts ins olving this

Comment: @Aryadeva The solution is suitably disgusting

Comment: Yes true...It needs the error function.@IdioticShrike

Comment: It depends what you mean by "solution". It is often the case that $\int f$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, and so the solutions to a differential equation, though they exist, also cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wolfram Alpha, the solution is $$\DeclareMathOperator{\erfi}{erfi}y(x) = c_1\cdot e^{-(3x^2)/2} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot i\sqrt{π/6}\cdot e^{1/6-(3 x^2)/2}\erfi(\frac{3x-i}{\sqrt{6}})-\frac{1}{2}i\sqrt{π/6}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{6}-(3 x^2)/2}\erfi({3x+i}{\sqrt{6}})$$
Which is an abominable mess. Linear ordinary differential equations are solvable, but always run the risk of being incredibly difficult! This isn't really an answer, but the solution just wouldn't fit into the comments.

If you're curious, "erfi" is the [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Correction: to the best of my understanding, a linear o.d.e of the form $y'(x)+Py=Q$, where $R,Q$ are strictly functions of $x$ *only*, is solvable if the integral $\int RQ\,dx$ is solvable, where $R$ is $e^{\int P\,dx}$ such that $Ry'(x)+RPy=RQ\implies\frac{d}{dx}[Ry]=RQ$. Here, it was solvable since the ridiculous integral of "RQ" (i.e. $\sin(x)e^{3x^2/2}$) was technically solvable by a computer.

Perhaps there are other forms of linear o.d.e that are not, in general, solvable, but I've yet to see them; hence why this is not really an answer, just a long comment.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac {dy}{dx} + 3xy = 0 \implies y=c\,e^{-\frac{3 x^2}{2}}$$ Variation of parameter leads to
$$\dfrac {dc}{dx}=\sin(x)\,e^{\frac{3 x^2}{2}}\implies c=\int  \sin(x)\,e^{\frac{3 x^2}{2}}\,dx + C$$

Just stay with that. I do not suppose that they expect you to know about the imaginary error function with, moreover, complex arguments.